# How to mount an Android file system on windows XP

Tags: android, android-ndk, samba, file-sharing

I'm compiling a program using gcc on the android through the shell, but want to edit the code on a windows XP machine.

In particular, I'm looking to a method to mount the root level of the android file system, not just the sdcard partitions.

ADB push and pull is too slow. Eclipse DDMS does not mount as su (superuser) and is a bit buggy. The android did not have NFS support.

Answer (score 2):

Samba is a free software re-implementation of the SMB/CIFS networking protocol. Samba Filesharing for android by funkyfresh is a Samba server available on the android to share sdcard data and is available at the play store. Samba requires a rooted android and superuser.

In order to share the root level of the android and not just the sdcard mounts, there is a [developer version of funkyfresh Samba](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8239139&postcount=128). By installing the developers version, the there is an option `don't rewrite smb.conf`, which does not exist in the public release.

To share the root, setup samba to include password, username, workgroup, netbios. This will by default share the sdcard and has an option to share a second sdcard under Other fileshare options. In the other options, I also disabled `no local master browser`. This will setup a share or two which can be mounted on windows just as if it were a `Microsoft windows network` as a member of a workgroup.

Once everything is working. Check the `don't rewrite smb.conf`. Then pull the `adb pull /data/data/com.funkyfresh.samba/files/smb.conf smb.conf` and change `path = /mnt/sdcard` to `path = /` save the file and `adb push smb.conf /data/data/com.funkyfresh.samba/files/smb.conf`

Once the file is replaced, disable and enable the sever. Now mount the share on the windows and view, edit, copy files from the android filesystem as a local share on the PC.